# Why does "write.dat" (R) save data files within folders?

Tags: r

In order to conduct some analysis using a particular software, I am required to have separate ".dat" files for each participant, with each file named as the participant number, all saved in one directory.

I have tried to do this using the "write.dat" function in R (from the 'multiplex' package).

I have written a loop that outputs a ".dat" file for each participant in a dataset. I would like each file that is outputted to be named the participant number, and for them all to be stored in the same folder.

```
## Using write.dat
participants_ID <- unique(newdata$SJNB)
for (i in 1:length(participants_ID)) {
  data_list[[i]] <-  newdata %>%
    filter(SJNB == participants_ID[i])
  write.dat(data_list[[i]], paste0("/Filepath/Directory/", participants_ID[i], ".dat"))
}

## Using write_csv this works perfectly:
participants_ID <- unique(newdata$SJNB)
for (i in 1:length(participants_ID)) {
  newdata %>%
    filter(SJNB == participants_ID[i]) %>%
    write_csv(paste0("/Filepath/Directory/", participants_ID[i], ".csv"), append = FALSE)
}
```

If I use the function "write_csv", this works perfectly (saving .csv files for each participant). However, if I use the function "write.dat" each participant file is saved inside a separate folder - the folder name is the participant number, and the file inside the folder is called "data_list[[i]]". In order to get all of the data_list files into the same directory, I then have to rename them which is time consuming.

I could theoretically output the files to .csv and then convert them to .dat, but I'm just intrigued to know if there's anything I could do differently to get the write.dat function to work the way I'm trying it :)

Comment: You should post the package which contains `write.dat` . Always do that for functions which are not in the base installation.

Comment: Thanks, I've added this to the question now.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on `write.dat` is subminimal, but it would appear that you have confused a directory *path* with a *file name* .  You have deliberately created a directory named "/Filepath/Directory/[participants_ID[i]].dat"  and that's where each output file is placed.   That you cannot assing a name to the `x.dat` file itself appears to be a defect in the package as supplied.

However, not all is lost.  Inside your loop,  replace your `write.dat` line with the following lines, or something similar (not tested):

### edit

It occurs to me that there's a smoother solution, albeit using the dreaded `eval`:
Again inside the loop, (assuming `participants_ID[i]` is a char string)

```
eval(paste0(participants_ID[i],'<- dataList[[i]]'))
write.dat(participants_ID[i], "/Filepath/Directory/")
```

#### previous answer

```
write.dat(data_list[[i]], "/Filepath/Directory/")
thecommand = paste0('mv /Filepath/Directory/dataList[[i]]  /Filepath/Directory/',[participants_ID[i]],'.dat',collapse="")
system(thecommand)
```