# How to use write.dat in R in a loop with changing name

Tags: r

I have several files that I have to export in `.dat` format. I want to creat a loop to export them with `write.dat`. Here under both ways I tried:

First: similar as the function write.csv:

```
library(lubridate)
library(multiplex)

files <- c("mtcars", "iris")
date <- today()

export <- function(x){
  write.dat(get(x), paste("~/save_path/", x, "-", date, sep = ""))
}

invisible(lapply(files, export))
```

This works very well with the function `write.csv`. However, `write.dat` only exports files named get(x) in folders with the desired name, as `write.dat` only allows to assign a path and not a name.

Secondly:

```
library(lubridate)
library(multiplex)

files <- c("mtcars", "iris")
date <- today()

export <- function(x){
  assign(paste(x, "-", date, sep = ""), get(x))
  y <- paste(x, "-", date, sep = "")
  write.dat(y , "~/save_path/")
}

invisible(lapply(files, export))
```

I tried to rename the data in such a way that it would be saved with the correct name. However, I was not able to pass the name in the first argument of the `write.dat` function.

I also tried to get inspiration from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074454/why-does-write-dat-r-save-data-files-within-folders), but without success.